# Socket.io chat, definindo url

Tags: php, html, html5, node.js, socket.io

Gostaria de uma ajuda com chat usando socket.io, gostaria de definir uma URL, não estou conseguindo, só consigo acessar pelo `localhost:3000`.

Por exemplo queria que o chat fosse na pagina inicial de meu site
exemplo: `siteexemplo.com.br`, como defino isso? como inicio o `server.js` dentro do servidor?

Meu código:

#### SERVER.JS

```
var socket  = require( './node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./node_modules/express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

#### chat.js

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
```

Outra duvida, como defino minha index, para PHP?

Fiz a alteração no código abaixo:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php'); 

});
```

Porém quando acesso o site, ele faz o download da pagina automaticamente...

Comment: O teu servidor é apache?

Comment: Sim, é apache...

Comment: Vou ver se consigo ajudar

Comment: Se perceberes bem inglês vê se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode

Comment: @Miguel E é possível rodar um NodeJs com servidor apache? Ou rodar o socket.io em um servidor apache? Pelo menos no servidor de hospedagem que utilizo não consegui isso justamente por essa limitação (segundo fui informado pelo suporte técnico).

Comment: Não é possível rodar NodeJS em servidores compartilhados pois o NodeJS necessita de acesso shell a qual hospedagens não-dedicadas não disponibilizam.

Comment: Qual seria a opção de fazer um chat então?

Answer (score -1):

Respondendo a tua segunda pergunta, se estás a usar um servidor Apache vais ao `httpd.conf` que normalmente esta localizado numa pasta +- assim dependendo da tua versão: Caminho de instalação `\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf`.

Abres o ficheiro, eu costumo abrir mesmo com o bloco de notas e localiza uma parte do ficheiro que diz `DirectoryIndex` (não esta comentado) e mudas o que esta a frente da propriedade para `index.php` ou outro nome qualquer com a extensão `php`.

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso, os dois não poderão ser na porta 3000, pois haverá um conflito de portas, o que recomendo nesse caso, é usar no server a porta 3001, enquanto isso a porta 3000 fica no front, sendo assim terá que usar dois npm start.

Answer (score -6):

Tem como sim só usar o socket.io-client eu utilizo nós meus projetos.

Site: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html